# exclude spring boot devtools (developmentOnly) dependencies from plain war packaging

Tags: gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Using the spring-boot-gradle plugin I declared the spring-boot-devtools jar as [developmentOnly](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools).

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.configuring.including-development-only-dependencies) developmentOnly jars are excluded from executable jar and war, but I need to deploy plain war to production and not the executable war. The plain war has developmentOnly (devtools) dependencies in it.

How can I exclude developmentOnly jars from plain war?